# Using programs with built in git support in a TFS 2013 shop

Tags: git, matlab, tfs, visual-studio-2013, rstudio

I work with a team that codes primarily in visual studio 2013 using TFS for source control, but we also do a substantial portion of our work coding in RStudio or Matlab for statistical computing tasks. Both RStudio and Matlab have built in support for git. Visual Studio 2013 also supposedly supports git.

Is there anyway to set things up so that users can use the built in support for git in Matlab/RStudio, but use our TFS server as a host for our code?

Alternatively, does any one have a suggestion for an alternative workflow that would work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the TFS projects set up to use GIT, in the TFS Server.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/13/git-for-tfs-2013.aspx describes the process.

[image]

You can migrate an existing project in TFS, there is a comment at the bottom of the age that says they did it using https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs.